# SQL query with multiple where clause

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to write a query for a dataset in SSRS. I have a joining table called `RequestSchools` which links to three other tables:

1. Schools
2. Placing Request
3. RequestSchoolType

I want to get the name of the `RequestedSchool (RequestedSchoolTypeId = 3)`

I also want the name of the `CatchmentSchool (RequestSchoolTypeId = 1)`

I've attached an image of the SQL query that I can get working with the requested school. I want the catchment school as well. Grateful for any help with this.

```
SELECT
    pr.PlacingRequestId, s.Name AS RequestedSchool
FROM  
    PlacingRequests AS pr 
INNER JOIN 
    RequestSchools AS rs ON rs.PlacingRequestId = pr.PlacingRequestId 
JOIN
    Schools s ON s.SchoolId = rs.SchoolId
WHERE
    rs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 3
```

[image: SQL Query with results]

Comment: You can paste you SQL query in your post, it will be helpfull!

Comment: please paste the actual code into the question, not an image. Also, seeing the database schema would make it a lot easier to comprehend.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but does `rs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 3 OR rs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 1` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is correct, as we can't see the schema, source data or a full example of the desired output, but I think this might be it:

```
SELECT 
  pr.PlacingRequestId, 
  s.Name as RequestedSchool,
  cs.Name as CatchmentSchool
FROM 
  PlacingRequests AS pr 
  INNER JOIN RequestSchools AS rs 
    ON rs.PlacingRequestId = pr.PlacingRequestId 
  INNER JOIN Schools s 
    on s.SchoolId = rs.SchoolId
    AND rs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 3 -- requested school
  INNER JOIN Schools cs 
    on cs.SchoolId = rs.SchoolId
    AND rs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 1 -- catchment school
```

Happy to update if it's not what you meant, and you can clarify the question as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

According what I understand about your requirement, you will be needing multiple joins and not another AND condition in the where clause. So we can omit the where here and join the requestschools with schools one more time for CatchmentSchool as we have done it once already for Requestedschool. Only difference is we are using the requestedtypeid and catchmenttypeid values while joining.

```
Select 
pr.PlacingRequestId, 
rs.Name as RequestedSchool
cs.Name as CatchmentSchool
FROM 
PlacingRequests AS pr 
INNER JOIN RequestSchools AS rrs 
ON rrs.PlacingRequestId = pr.PlacingRequestId 
and rrs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 3 
JOIN Schools rs 
on rs.SchoolId = rrs.SchoolId
INNER JOIN RequestSchools AS crs 
ON crs.PlacingRequestId = pr.PlacingRequestId 
and crs.RequestSchoolTypeId = 1 
JOIN Schools cs 
on cs.SchoolId = crs.SchoolId
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a CASE function, but I don't know which RDBMS you are using so here is the brute force approach: just run your query as two sub-queries, each specifying a different type ID and then join them. It would be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT catch.placingrequestid, catch.catchmentschool, requested.requestedschool
FROM
(SELECT pr.placingrequestid, s.nam as catchmentschool
FROM (PlacingRequest pr
INNER JOIN RequestSchools rs ON pr.placingrequestid = rs.placingrequestid)
INNER JOIN School s ON rs.schoolid = s.schoolid
WHERE rs.requestschooltypeid = 1) catch
INNER JOIN
(SELECT pr.placingrequestid, s.nam as requestedschool
FROM (PlacingRequest pr
INNER JOIN RequestSchools rs ON pr.placingrequestid = rs.placingrequestid)
INNER JOIN School s ON rs.schoolid = s.schoolid
WHERE rs.requestschooltypeid = 3) requested
ON catch.placingrequestid = requested.placingrequestid
```